# React useState doesn't hold/ store values from API/SDK data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

This is probably a redundant questions.... I'am able to store an object with useState and render such values but after some 'idle' time, the state disappears. I am grabbing data from an SDK (firstname, lastname...) which I can use this information for placeholder in my form.

For my use, I've created a raw multi-step dynamic form, living on the same component, where users will answer 1 question at a time before proceeding to the next step. The last step renders all the user's information which sometimes show and sometimes throws an error user.firstName is undefined probably due to the time it takes a user to answer the questions 'idle' time..

```
import { User } from 'randomSDK';

const FormComponent = () => {
 let [user, setUser] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
  async fetchData(){
   let _user = await User.getUserInfo();
// Result user ={firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'}
   setUser(_user)
  }
fetchData()
 ), []}

 return (
  <form>
    <input placeholder={user.firstName} type='text' />
  // sometimes user.firstName shows
  // other times- TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

  // etc....
  </form>
 )
}

export default FormComponent;
```

Should I create some sorta of redux from loosing this data on render???

Perhaps I should be setting up a test case assuming there's no such data in placement of user.firstName..

I've tried the following and still get the same error:

```
<input placeholder={user.firstName || ''} />
<input placeholder={!user.firstName ? '' : user.firstName} />
```

I'm sure this is a something very, very simple fix where I'm just making it too complicated..

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because your useEffect runs multiple time.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  async fetchData(){
   let _user = await User.getUserInfo();
// Result user ={firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'}
   setUser(_user)
  }
  fetchData();
 ), []} //add dependancy array //
```

Please see if this works.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include this in the code part of question as well. That's exactly how I have it and with the dependency array. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Can you add the whole code then? Like how are you setting state through that input and all. Would be helpful if the code of whole component is available.

Comment: There's no way I can post this component with so many lines of code. Hence, I broke it down to the simplest, basic, and raw understanding of how i used useState and useEffect. 

It's literally declaring the component, declare variable for useState, useEffect to make async/await call to SDK and setState of that object. For the sake of this example, let's saying 2 inputs type=text, placeholder1 ={user.firstName} placeholder2={user.lastName}. It seems as if by the time the form reaches to render these states, it's loses memory. why is that